# Rudin Chapter 3 exercise 14

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

For exercise 14c of Baby Rudin:

If $\{s_n\}$ is a complex sentence, define its arithmetic means $\sigma_n$ by 
$$\sigma_n = \frac{s_0 + s_1 + \cdots + s_n}{n + 1},$$
where $n = 0, 1, 2, ...$

14c: Can it happen that $s_n>0$ for all $n$ and that $\limsup s_n = \infty$, although $\lim \sigma_n = 0$?

Does my example of $s_n = \sqrt{n}$ work?

My attempt:

It is clear that $\limsup s_n = \infty$ since $\sqrt{n} \rightarrow \infty$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

And $\sigma_n = \frac{1 + \sqrt{2} + \cdots + \sqrt{n}}{n + 1}$, so $$\begin{split}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \sigma_n &= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1 + \sqrt{2} + \cdots + \sqrt{n}}{n + 1}\\
&= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1/\sqrt{n} + 2/\sqrt{n}+ \cdots + 1}{\sqrt{n} + 1/\sqrt{n}} = 0
\end{split}$$

Comment: It is not clear how you prove the last equality (=0). It's a sum of n "zero" term

Comment: Wouldn't all the 1/sqrt{n} terms just go to 0?

Comment: How about $\frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n} +\cdots \frac{1}{n}$ ($n$-terms)? All the terms goes to zero.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks!

Comment: You want something that averages to 0 but actually has a couple terms shooting off to infinity. See if you can modify the classic $(-1)^n$ example to suit your needs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example does not work since

$$\frac{1}{n+1} \sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{k} \geqslant \frac{1}{n+1}\int_0^n \sqrt{x} \, dx = \frac{2n^{3/2}}{3(n+1)}= \frac{2 \sqrt{n}}{3 + 3/n} \to \infty$$

Comment: @MessyTiger:  Try something like $s_0 = 1$ , $s_n = k$ for $n = 2^k$ and $s_n = 1/n$ otherwise.  The sequence is unbounded and positive but the Cesaro sum converges to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider 1 followed by a block of 1/2's, then 2 followed by a block of 1/4's etc. It is easy to see what the sizes of these blocks have to be to make this sequence work.